# Compute the sum and the convergence radius for $1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I know that $$1+\frac{1}{1-x}=1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k\Rightarrow1+\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}=1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k}=1+\frac{1}{1+x^2},$$

Dividing the rightmost terms by $x$ i get:

$$1+\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}=1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k-1},$$

Integrating termwise i get

$$x+\ln{x}-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(1+x^2)}=x+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}.$$

This is not really the correct answer. The book says it's:

$$1-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(1+x^2)}, \quad |x|\leq1.$$

**EDIT:** I now see I've messed upp the bounds. In my original limit its from 1, then o forget to go from 0 to 1 again. However the question below still remains!

**Question:** Is there any systematic step-by-step approach for these types of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $k=0$ for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}(-1)^{k}x^{2k-1}$ in doing integration from $0$ to $x$ is a little problematic, one splits it out to get
\begin{align*}
1+\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{x}{1+x^{2}}=1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum_{k=1}(-1)^{k}x^{2k-1},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
-\dfrac{x}{1+x^{2}}=\sum_{k=1}(-1)^{k}x^{2k-1},
\end{align*}
then doing integration from $0$ to $x$ is just fine:
\begin{align*}
-\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^{2})=\sum_{k=1}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{x^{2k}}{2k},
\end{align*}
now adding both sides by $1$ to get the result.

Comment: What happened to the integration constant?

Comment: Because I am doing the definite integral, which is from $0$ to $x$, there is no such constant, that is, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}-\dfrac{t}{1+t^{2}}dt=\cdots$

Comment: Thanks, I got it!