# Is is possible to find sum for this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

$$\lim _{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i\frac{x^{2i}}{2i}$$

I have found an inequality that this equation satisfies but I am clueless if a solution to this already exists, in which case I would love to learn about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2588058/42969

Comment: Although the question is poorly written (e.g. an equation cannot satisfy an inequality; and what is displayed is not an equation), it is pretty clear what the intended meaning is.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^i\frac{x^{2i}}{2i}=-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^{i-1}\frac{\left(x^2\right)^i}{i}=-\frac12\ln(1+x^2)$$where we used the series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Series).